# there is problem to access the foreach array contains a value

Tags: php

```
foreach($ev as $evn){
    $events[]=array("event"=>$evn['EVTID']);
}
```

output:

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [event] => 3 ) [1] => Array ( [event] => 2 ) )
```

I need to check this

```
if(in_array(3, $events, true)) {
     echo "'3' found with strict check\n"
}
else {
    echo "fail";
}
```

The 3 element present in array but result is fail

Answer (score 2):

You need to use [`array_column`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php) to access the values in the `event` column directly. Try this:

```
if(in_array(3, array_column($events, 'event'), true)) {
     echo "'3' found with strict check\n";
}
else {
    echo "fail";
}
```

[Demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/5KFgI)

Note that with the `strict` parameter set true, a value of `3` will not match a string `'3'`. If your array has string values in it, you will need to either remove the `strict` check i.e.

```
if(in_array(3, array_column($events, 'event'))) {
```

or change the search value to `'3'` i.e.

```
if(in_array('3', array_column($events, 'event'), true)) {
```

Alternatively you can ensure the values in your array are integers by changing this line:

```
$events[]=array("event"=>$evn['EVTID']);
```

to

```
$events[]=array("event"=>(int)$evn['EVTID']);
```

Comment: echo $events[0]['event']; it print 3 and if(in_array(3, array_column($events, 'event'), true)) {
     echo "'3' found with strict check\n"
}
else {
    echo "fail";
} this displays result fail

Comment: @RoshanKolte if you look at my demo the code is working fine... perhaps your value is actually a string? what happens if you `var_dump($events[0]['event']);`?

Comment: But does not true with my code the when i try it the result will fail i have try the same code as above

Comment: @RoshanKolte did you try `var_dump($events[0]['event']);`? what does that give?

Comment: var_dump($events[0]['event']); output string(1) "3"

Comment: Ok, so that is your problem. You are setting the `strict` check, and in that mode, the string `'3'` is not equal to the integer `3`. You can either remove the strict check, or change your search value to `'3'`. Or in  your foreach loop you can change `"event"=>$evn['EVTID']` to `"event"=>(int)$evn['EVTID']`